# Rotation webkit problem when spinning like a compass

Tags: javascript, webkit, compass-geolocation

this is my simple function ('mycompass' is a div in my body)

```
function watchCompass() {

    var suc = function(a){       
        var r =a.magneticHeading;  
        document.getElementById('mycompass').style.webkitTransform  = "rotateZ("+-r+"deg)";  
    };
    var fail = function(){};
    var opt = {};
    opt.frequency = 50;
    timer = navigator.compass.watchHeading(suc,fail,opt);
}
```

for some reason when the compass 'wheel' does a complete rotation from 0 to 360 it goes back to 0 and not to the "virtual" 361... etc.. is not able to understand that from 0 and 360 there is no difference ...

and I don't know how to calculate a way to have the wheel spining smoothy clockwise and anticlockwise

another way to put this question is:

how can i rotate my objext from, for instance, from 15deg to 270deg, in anti-clockwise direction instead of clockwise? how can i tell my script that vale?

Comment: You already asked this question, and I already gave you an answer. You're going to have to post more code; you've left out "navigator", "compass", the "watchHeading" function, etc etc.  This is not really a Javascript question, it's more about simple modulo arithmetic.

Comment: i keep asking becuase i'm kind surprise no one is really able to solve this.

Comment: in this example if you click first E clokwise, then S
it simple does what the sript does.

Comment: You've already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348185/compass-spinning-javascript-problem-with-angle-rotate-translate. Asking the same question multiple times just creates noise. If you want to provide more information to your previous question, just edit it.

Comment: *You* can't solve it. I can, and did. If you can't figure out how to do modulo arithmetic *with a complete example right in front of you*, well, have a nice life, and godspeed.

Comment: is this website supposed to find solution or meet nerd scum that say "solve by yourself"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my workaround but i stil have problem when the wheel degree == -360 or 360

```
var angle = 0;
var lastAngle = 0;




   function watchCompass() {

          var suc = function(a){
          var angle = roundNyc(a.magneticHeading);

       l1 = angle -  lastAngle;
       l2 = 360 - l1;

      if( Math.abs(l1) >=  Math.abs(l2)){ 

       r =   (lastAngle - l2) ; 

      }else{

       r =  angle ; 

      }    

       lastAngle = r;     
       l1 = 0;
       l2 = 0;

   document.getElementById('mycompass').style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(' + -r + 'deg)';

          };
          var fail = function(){};
          var opt = {};
          opt.frequency = 50;
          timer = navigator.compass.watchHeading(suc,fail,opt);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, here is an example of how to do this: http://gutfullofbeer.net/compass.html

Comment: I still dont think thi sis the right example because this compass is dumb ad doesnt recognize the shortest lenght between two point, it simply goes from A to B without asking "is shorter to go from A to B clokwise or go from B backward?"
like a real compass